# Are these events independent or not

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

I was given this exercise:
[image]

So, this is my reasoning:

> Two events are independent if the outcome of one of those events does
> not depend on the outcome of the other event. Independent events are
> not affected by other events. When events A and B are independent:
>
> P(B) = P(B|A)
>
> P(A∩B) = P(A)P(B)

Then

```
A: "Heads came out" event.
B: event "exactly two balls were obtained red, and there may be blue between them".
```

> If the event mentioned in 'A' was fulfilled, then event 'B': "exactly
> two balls were obtained red, and there may be blue between them" may
> or may not happen (in this case a balanced die of 6 faces and is
> extracted with replacement that quantity obtained in the dice of balls
> of the box) It is different if in the event "heads came out" it did
> not happen later, event 'B' "exactly two balls were obtained in red,
> and there may be blue between them" it may or may not happen (in this
> case we proceed to remove a ball from the box until it comes out blue)

```
P(B) = P(B|A)
P(B|A) = probability of event 'B' given that event 'A' was fulfilled.
P(B) = probability of event B.
A: "Heads came out" event.
B: event "exactly two balls were obtained red, and there may be blue between them".
P(B) = probability that exactly two balls were obtained red, and there may be blue between them.
We cannot calculate P (B) until we obtain the result of the event 'A'.
P(B) when the event 'A' occurs is different from P (B) when the event does not occur.
Therefore P(B) ≠ P(B|A), that is, the events 'A' and 'B' are not independent.
```

Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: Your assumption appears to be that the events are not independent. I think you are supposed to determine whether or not they are independent, by actually computing the probabilities, not assume that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because the specifics of how event B might happen depend on the result of event A does *not* guarantee that the events are independent in a *probabilistic* sense. Instead, you have enough information to fully calculate the probabilities:

|  | Event $A$ occurs | Event $A$ does not occur |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Event $B$ occurs** | $P(A \cap B)$ | $P(\lnot A \cap B)$ | $P(B)$ |
| **Event $B$ does not occur** | $P(A \cap \lnot B)$ | $P(\lnot A \cap \lnot B)$ | $P(\lnot B)$ |
|  | $P(A)$ | $P(\lnot A)$ | $1$ |

If you can show that each of the interior cells is the product of its respective margins, then the events are independent.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
I do not really understand why in this particular case my answer would not be alright. I get your point but not really sure

Comment: @programming_amazing, your answer is wrong for two reasons. You make the claim, “$P(B)$ when the event $A$ occurs is different from $P(B)$ when the event does not occur,” without actually showing that, i.e. computing the probabilities. For a correct answer, you need to show that these probabilities are different (if they are), not just say they are different. You also incorrectly claim that “we cannot compute $P(B)$ until...” That probability can be computed from the information given in the problem.

Comment: All of your "it may or may not happen"s are events whose probabilities you can calculate exactly, and you *can* find P(B|A) and P(B|!A) and from that P(B). Without having done the calculations myself, it would not surprise me if this question was designed *specifically* to counter your guess - i.e. the processes for drawing the balls will give exactly the same probability of event B, so that event B becomes independent of event A.